# git bash clip command return weird characters

Tags: bash, git, encoding

windows os. vscode git bash terminal. entered the command below with Russian characters:

"git log -1 --pretty=format:%s | clip"

if you then paste the result from the clipboard (ctrl + V) into the terminal, strange characters appear, although git log correctly displays Russian characters.

Comment: Is your terminal using utf8? or another encoding?

Comment: `clip` is not a ´bash command. After all, bash has no concept of a "clipboard". Windows **does** have a command named _clip_, but there may of course be other commands of this name around as well. Please clarify what you are doing here exactly, i.e. which `clip` you are using, and which terminal application you are using.

Comment: In bash this will only write whatever you're echoing in a new `clip` file.

Comment: Git isn't really relevant here. (Bash is the Bourne-Again Shell and "git bash" is simply a *port* of bash *to* Windows, so that Git—which needs a POSIX-ish shell to exist—can be used *on* Windows. So Windows Git comes with bash so that Git can run, but that doesn't make bash part of Git.)

Comment: In any case, this is definitely some kind of encoding issue. Windows internally uses UTF-16-LE but Unix-ish systems "prefer" UTF-8. (Git tries to be largely encoding agnostic, just storing any bytes you shove into it, but does have its own ability to cross-code from one encoding to another, using an "encoding" header in a commit. But here you're not using Git, you're just using bash.)

Comment: i am working in vscode terminal.
I want to save the current commit theme to the clipboard before I do a head reset.
git log - shows the commit topic correctly.